# Computing $U \times V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Problem:

Given
$$ U = (2,1,3) $$
$$ U = (4,-2,2) $$
find $U \times V$.

Answer:

\begin{align*}
U \times V &= \begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
2 & 1 & 3 \\
4 & -2 & 2
\end{vmatrix} =
i \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
-2 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix} - j \begin{vmatrix}
2 &  3 \\
4 & 2
\end{vmatrix} + k \begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
4 & -2
\end{vmatrix} \\
U \times V &=
i(2 + 6) - j(4-12) + k(-4-4) \\
U \times V &= 8i + 8j - 8k
\end{align*}

However, the books answer is:
$$ (5,8,-6) $$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I  dont think you have done anything wrong.  If you have stated the problem correctly, then the book's answer is wrong.

Comment: You have two vectors called $U$, and none called $V$.

Comment: Since your second $U$ has all entries even, the cross product must also have all entries even. So maybe you copied that vector down wrong. Or maybe it's a typo.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The problem had a vector called U and a vector called V. I did the  problem on paper first and made a typo posting the question, I now believe that I am right and the book is  wrong.

Comment: OK, but you still have two vectors called $U$, and none called $V$. Assuming that the second $U$ is really $V$, your calculations are correct. You can always check a cross product calculation $u\times v$ by seeing whether $u\cdot(u\times v)=0$ and $v\cdot(u\times v)=0$ – if those two equations don't hold, then something is wrong.

Comment: Given that $U$ is perpendicular to the book's cross-product, while $V$ is not, and that both of you agree on the $j$ coefficient of the cross-product, which depends on the first and third coordinates of $V$, but not the middle coordinate, it seems likely that the $V$ vector they gave in the problem statement has a different 2nd coordinate than  they used in producing the answer. And sure enough, setting $V = (4, -1, 2)$ gives their answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP isn't responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given is correct subject to a typo. That is, the second vectori is $V$ not $U$.